# Complex join 3 tables with sum and group by

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sum

I'm trying to generate a report for one of our departments that pulls data from 3 tables. The basic structure is below:

```
CREATE TABLE `evd_us_county_mio_2018q4` (
    `state_code` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `state_abbr` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `county_code` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `county_name` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `vehicle_category` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `vehicle_segmentation` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `vehicle_make` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `vehicle_model` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `vehicle_model_year` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `vehicle_fuel_type` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `vehicle_engine_displacement_ccs` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `vehicle_engine_cylinders` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `vehicle_count` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `codes_usa` (
    `id` MEDIUMINT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `company_id` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL,
    `postal_code` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `place_name` VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL COMMENT 'city',
    `admin_name1` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'state',
    `admin_code1` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'state_alpha',
    `admin_name2` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'county_name',
    `admin_code2` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `admin_name3` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `admin_code3` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `latitude` FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,
    `longitude` FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,
    `accuracy` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `postal_code` (`postal_code`),
    INDEX `company_id` (`company_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=43644
;
```

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `company` (
    `id` SMALLINT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `account_number` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    `distributorship` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'added 11-21-17 for the Directory page to distinguish between companies that were actual distributorships and other companies or resellers',
    `name` VARCHAR(70) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `address` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `address2` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `address3` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `address4` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `city` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `state_province_region` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `postal_code` VARCHAR(12) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `country` CHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `shipping_address` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `shipping_address2` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `shipping_address3` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `shipping_address4` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `shipping_city` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `shipping_state_province_region` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `shipping_postal_code` VARCHAR(12) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `shipping_country` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `UPS_address` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `UPS_address2` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `UPS_address3` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `UPS_address4` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `UPS_city` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `UPS_state_province_region` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `UPS_postal_code` VARCHAR(12) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `UPS_country` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `phone` VARCHAR(25) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `fax` VARCHAR(25) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `web` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `zone` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `zone_country_codes` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT 'USA' COMMENT 'Country code to reference the postal_codes table',
    `date_established` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `order_frequency` TINYINT(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `on_hand_inventory` TINYINT(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `last_updated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `deactivation_date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `account_number` (`account_number`),
    INDEX `company_name` (`name`),
    INDEX `zone_country_codes` (`zone_country_codes`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=908
;
```

[image]

**UPDATE**
I originally though my results were accurate; after showing a sample to the department that will be using the data, and looking at previous years numbers, I determined my query is still not quite right. The following query is not returning accurate results:

```
SELECT a.state_abbr, a.county_name, SUM(a.vehicle_count) AS vehicle_count, c.NAME AS distributorship
FROM import_experian.evd_us_county_mio_2018q4 a
LEFT JOIN postal.codes_usa b
     ON a.state_abbr=b.admin_code1 AND a.county_name = b.admin_name2
    LEFT JOIN headquarters.company c
     ON b.company_id=c.id
WHERE a.vehicle_category = 'Offroad'
GROUP BY a.state_abbr, a.county_name
ORDER BY a.state_abbr, a.county_name
LIMIT 100
```

[image]

I know this is inaccruate because querying for the total vehicle count in AK only returns ~27k:

```
SELECT a.state_abbr, sum(a.vehicle_count) AS vehicle_count
FROM import_experian.evd_us_county_mio_2018q4 a 
WHERE a.vehicle_category = 'Offroad' AND a.state_abbr = 'AK'
```

[image]

and `GROUP BY a.county_name` shows far fewer vehicles in each county as well:

```
SELECT a.state_abbr, a.county_name, sum(a.vehicle_count) AS vehicle_count
FROM import_experian.bg_products_evd_us_county_mio_2018q4 a 
WHERE a.vehicle_category = 'Offroad' AND a.state_abbr = 'AK'
GROUP BY a.county_name
```

[image]

It seems when I addd the `JOIN` statements that the `SUM()` of `vehicle_count` is being multiplied if a company exists. For example, notice that without the `JOIN` statement, Anchorage shows `8,193` for the `vehicle_count` which is the correct number, the same for Fairbanks North Star:

[image]

Comparing the above results to the result from the query with `JOIN` statements reveals something interesting:

[image]

Achorage is not associated with any company at this time and the SUM() is accurate while Fairbanks North Star does have a company associated an the SUM() is X times the true value.

What am I missing here? How can I fix my query?

Thank you!

Comment: Start by trying to get the correct results. Your GROUP BY clause is probably invalid, try `GROUP BY a.county_name,  C.name` ( I assume a.state_abbr is functionally dependent of a.county_name, but it's hard to tell from the info you provided ). You will get better help if you provide `CREATE TABLE` statements including keys

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Regarind the functional dependencies, states can potentially share county names. For instance, there may be a `Ford` county in both Kansas and `Oklahoma`. Taking this into consideration, it may even be necessary to `GROUP BY` the `state` `county` and `comany`? I updated my post with the CREATE statements. I know the structure is probably not ideal; I am working with existing data. I'm open to any suggestions to improve the situation.

Comment: `2018q4` -- Don't use multiple tables.

Comment: Thanks for your input; what do you mean by "don't use multiple tables?"

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add a full GROUP BY to get deterministic result:

```
SELECT a.state_abbr, a.county_name, SUM(a.vehicle_count) AS vehicle_count, C.name
FROM import_experian.bg_products_evd_us_county_mio_2018q4 a 
JOIN bgprod_postal.codes_usa b
     ON a.state_abbr=b.admin_code1 AND a.county_name = b.admin_name2
JOIN bgprod_headquarters.company c
     ON b.company_id=c.id
WHERE a.vehicle_category = 'Offroad'
GROUP BY a.state_abbr, a.county_name, C.name 
LIMIT 100;
```

For efficiency, you may want to create an index on:

```
CREATE INDEX ... ON import_experian.bg_products_evd_us_county_mio_2018q4
    (state_abbr, county_name, vehicle_category);
```

If vehicle_category is very selective you may change that to:

```
CREATE INDEX ... ON import_experian.bg_products_evd_us_county_mio_2018q4
    (vehicle_category, state_abbr, county_name);
```

In addition to that, you may want to create an index on:

```
CREATE INDEX ... ON bgprod_postal.codes_usa
    (admin_code1, admin_name2);
```

One way to add a YEAR dimension to the result, is to add a constant to each leg of a union like:

```
SELECT 2018 as origin, a.state_abbr, a.county_name, SUM(a.vehicle_count) AS vehicle_count, C.name
FROM import_experian.bg_products_evd_us_county_mio_2018q4 a 
JOIN bgprod_postal.codes_usa b
     ON a.state_abbr=b.admin_code1 AND a.county_name = b.admin_name2
JOIN bgprod_headquarters.company c
     ON b.company_id=c.id
WHERE a.vehicle_category = 'Offroad'
GROUP BY a.state_abbr, a.county_name, C.name 
UNION ALL
SELECT 2019 as origin, a.state_abbr, a.county_name, SUM(a.vehicle_count) AS vehicle_count, C.name
FROM import_experian.bg_products_evd_us_county_mio...
...
```

That you get duplicate results is a consequence of that you don't have any real keys in your tables (an autogenerated id is useless when it comes to integrity issues). To figure out what is wrong you need to think through what the real keys should be, group by them and apply having count(1) > 1. Those rows are your culprits.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. Your suggestion was correct. I will look into adding the indexes. If you have time, could you consider the update I made concerning the bonus requirement of running this same query for additional years and merging it into one report? Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately I seems that the query is still multiplying the SUM() somehow. If I just run the first part of the query and group by state to get the sum for each state, Alaska (AK) is only returning ~27k as the sum. Looking at the sample query you can see that the totals for AK are far greater. Need to do some more tweaking.